# Four-velocities, geodesics and antisymmetry in Christoffel symbols

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, geodesics

It might be just a basic confusion, but couldn't find an answer. Given the geodesic equation:

$$\frac{d^{2}x^{\lambda}}{d\tau^{2}}+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda} \frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau} \frac{dx^{\nu}}{d\tau}=\frac{du^{\lambda}}{d\tau}+\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda} u^{\mu}u^{\nu}=0$$

If we multiply by $u_{\lambda}$, then based on $u_{\lambda}u^{\lambda}=c^{2}$ we get:

$$u_{\lambda}\frac{du^{\lambda}}{d\tau}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d(u_{\lambda}u^{\lambda})}{d\tau}=0=-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}u_{\lambda}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}$$

Which would imply that $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$ is antisymmetric in the $\lambda, \mu$ indices. This isn't the case for the Levi-Civita connection. What am I missing?

Edit: Just to address the "Why does this imply antisymmetry?" point. The same rational for antisymmetry is invoked for the field tensor in electromagnetism: https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/1-png.256873/

Edit 2: Some nice answers but the problem remains. Another thing to keep in mind: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%27s_theorem_(relativity)

Edit 3: The solution was given basically by the top voted answer. A bit more explicit:
$$u_{\lambda}\frac{du^{\lambda}}{d\tau}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}=-\frac{1}{2}\partial^{\lambda}g_{\mu\nu}u_{\lambda}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}=-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}u_{\lambda}u^{\mu}u^{\nu}$$
where the last equality follows from the definition of $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\lambda}$ for the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: Why do you assume that $\frac{du^{\lambda}}{d\tau}=0$?

Comment: @schris38 I don't. It's the product $u_{\lambda}\frac{du^{\lambda}}{d\tau}$ that is zero because $u_{\lambda}u^{\lambda}$ is a constant.

Comment: the fact that $u_{\lambda}u^{\lambda}$ is constant does not tell you that the product $u_{\lambda}\frac{d u^{\lambda}}{d\tau}=0$.

Comment: @schris38 Yes, it does. It a basic thing proven in any course: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node115.html

Comment: If a tensor $A_{\mu\nu}$ is antisymmetric, that implies $A_{\mu\nu} x^\mu x^\nu = 0$ for some vector $x^\mu$. But I'm not sure that the reverse is necessarily true. For example, you have $\eta_{\mu\nu} x^\mu x^\nu = 0$ for lightlike trajectories, but that doesn't imply antisymmetry of the metric.

Comment: @LenardKasselmann Good point. So, lack of antisymmetry implies constraints on the type of trajectory you can have. The geodesic equation does that, but not sure if that solves the whole matter. It applies for any velocity you'd have in free fall for any particle. This generality makes me more inclined towards antisymmetry, but it could just be a property of all trajectories in free fall.

Comment: In the last term of the first equation $\lambda$ appears twice as an upper index. A mistake?

Comment: @Amit Yes, it was a typo. I corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: @Sebby No, I think that's exactly the point. It's not true for any vector. If you pick a trajectory which is not a geodesic, then the term will not be zero, thus proving that the connection is not antisymmetric.

Comment: @LenardKasselmann Your line of reasoning is the most convincing. However, the argument I invoke for the antisymmetry is also made for the field tensor in electromagnetism (see the edit). You can argue the argument holds in electromagnetism only for velocities $u_{\lambda}u^{\lambda}=c^{2}$, but that's for any physical case. Similarly, the argument I make might be for specific velocities but then again it's all the velocities in free fall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote
$$u_\lambda \frac{du^\lambda}{d\tau} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{d(u_\lambda u^\lambda)} {d\tau} = 0$$
because $u_\lambda u^\lambda = c^2$. But the first equality is ONLY true for special relativity, i.e. for flat space. If we consider curved space with an arbitrary metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, we have, by definition
$$u_\lambda u^\lambda = g_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu$$
Taking the derivative gives,
$$\frac{d(u_\lambda u^\lambda)}{d\tau} = \frac{d (g_{\mu\nu})} {d\tau}u^\mu u^\nu + g_{\mu\nu} \frac{d u^\mu}{d\tau} u^\nu +g_{\mu\nu} \frac{d u^\nu}{d\tau} u^\mu = \frac{d (g_{\mu\nu})} {d\tau}u^\mu u^\nu + 2 g_{\mu\nu} u^\mu \frac{du^\nu}{d\tau}$$
$$=\frac{d (g_{\mu\nu})} {d\tau}u^\mu u^\nu + 2 u_\lambda \frac{d u^\lambda}{d \tau}$$
where for the second equality, I used the fact that the metric is always symmetric. In general, the first term will not be zero! The value of the metric will change from point to point along the geodesic.

Here's an example. Consider the metric for 2D polar coordinates:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & r^2 
\end{pmatrix}
In this case, we have
$$\frac{d g_{11}}{d\tau} = \frac{d (r^2)}{d\tau} = \frac{d(r^2)}{dr} \frac{dr}{d\tau} = 2r \frac{dr}{d\tau}$$
If you, for example, consider a radial path, this quantity will not be zero.

In flat space (in globally Minkowskian coordinates), the metric is constant along the geodesic, and the Christoffel symbols are zero, so your relation is trivially true.

Also note that the proof you linked is from a course on special relativity, so it only uses Lorentz transformations, not more general coordinate transformation between non-inertial frames that you have to consider when you do GR.

Comment: The rabbit hole goes deeper. There's Birkhoff's theorem that says any spherically symmetric solution of the vacuum field equations must be static and asymptotically flat. So, $\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau} = 0$ even for general relativity.

Comment: @Sebby First, Birkhoff's theorem is not a general statement. As you said, it only applies to spherically symmetric solutions. Also, I don't see how Birkhoff's Theorem would imply $\frac{d g_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau} = 0$. Asymptotically flat means that curvature vanishes in the limit of large distances. When you take the derivative, you look at changes over small distances. I added an explicit example where the derivative of the metric is not zero.

Comment: The word static, you can take $\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau}=\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{dt}\frac{dt}{d\tau} = 0$. What I wanted to point out is that the problem applies to most common applications of general relativity. It's not some obscure or artificial setting, it's front and centre in the most used cases.

Comment: @Sebby No, in general, the proper time does not only depend on the coordinate time. The proper time is given by $d\tau^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$, so for example in minkowskian coordinates $\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau}  = \frac{\partial g_{\mu\nu}}{\partial t} \frac{\partial t}{\partial \tau} + \frac{\partial  g_{\mu\nu}}{ \partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau} + \dots$

Comment: There's another problem with your answer and calculation, much more basic than invoking Birkhoff's theorem. If $\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau}$ is not zero, then by your calculation it should vary in the precise way as to cancel out the contribution of the velocity $u$ of an arbitrary particle. So any particle in free fall would influence the gravitational field of the source in some notable way. This doesn't seem causal or elegant.

Comment: In calculating $\frac{dg_{\mu\nu}}{d\tau}$ I had this in mind: https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node114.html#e10.105 but it might not generalize to arbitrary spacetimes.

Comment: @sebby It doesn't. Again, these articles are about special relativity and flat spacetime.

Comment: @sebby Regarding the other comment: Take a close look at the Geodesic equation and remember how the Connection is defined. It is constructed out of derivatives of the metric. So yes, in a sense, the metric varies in such a way as to cancel the derivative of the 4-velocity. That's the whole point of  the Geodesic equation. I find it very elegant :)

Comment: I wasn't referring to the geodesic equation when talking about the change in metric. I was referring to your calculation. The change in metric would be an odd feature and caused by the falling particle. I find this very strange. The geodesic equation just says how the particle falls according to the geometry of the spacetime. The change of metric to keep $u_{\lambda}u^{\lambda} = c^{2}$ is a distinct thing and doesn't seem quite right to me. Never encountered this in any book or course. A reference to back this line of reasoning up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm confused why do you think that $$\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu} u_\lambda u^\mu  u^\nu=0$$

implies some sort of anti-symmetry for $\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\lambda$. For starters, you should recall that $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}$ appearing in this formula is just $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x(\tau))$, i.e., only over that particular curve, so you would hardly be able to infer a general property of the functions $\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(x)$ away from that curve by looking at a single geodesic equation.

Second, and more relevant, $u^\mu$ is just one vector. You cannot infer that $\Gamma$ is anti-symmetric because that identity holds for just one vector. If it were anti-symmetric, the identity would hold for any vector. If it holds for a single vector you cannot infer the converse.

Example: consider the matrix

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0.\end{pmatrix}$$

Then given $e_3 = (0,0,1)$ we have $Ae_3=0$. Of course this implies $A_{ij} e_3^i e_3^j=0$. Nevertheless the matrix $A$ is clearly not anti-symmetric.

Comment: It's for any velocity of any particle. Also, the argument is invoked for the antisymmetry of the field tensor in electromagnetism: https://www.physicsforums.com/attachments/1-png.256873/

Comment: Another thing: the example you give is a singular matrix. A non-singular example would be more convincing. At least one of the Christoffel matrices $\Gamma^{\lambda}$ is non-singular for the Schwarzschild solution. $\Gamma^{1}$ in the derivation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Schwarzschild_solution#Calculating_the_Christoffel_symbols

Answer (score 3):

Even in flat space there are coordinates where the Christoffel symbols are not antisymmetric in a lower and the upper index:

Take the Minkowski metric in spherical coordinates [1]:
$$
ds^2=-c^2\,dt+dr^2+r^2(d\vartheta^2+\sin^2\vartheta\,d\varphi^2)\,.
$$
Then (the list is incomplete but sufficient),
\begin{align}
\Gamma^r_{\varphi\varphi}&=-r\sin^2\vartheta\,,&\Gamma^\varphi_{r\varphi}&=\frac{1}{r}\,, \\[2mm]
\Gamma^\vartheta_{\varphi\varphi}&=-\sin\vartheta\cos\vartheta\,,
&\Gamma^\varphi_{\vartheta\varphi}&=\cot\vartheta\,.
\end{align}

The following Lemma that I found [here](https://people.ucsc.edu/%7Ermont/classes/differential_forms/lectures/christoffel_forms.pdf) has interesting consequences:

***$S_3$-Lemma.*** *Let $\gamma_{abc}$ be an arbitrary set of numbers that depend on three indices. If $\gamma_{abc}$ is symmetric in $b,c$ and antisymmetric in $a,b$ it is zero.*

Proof. By the (anti)-symmetries,
$$
\gamma_{abc}=-\gamma_{bac}=-\gamma_{bca}=\gamma_{cba}=\gamma_{cab}\,.
$$
That is, the sign does not change when we move the last index to the front.
Therefore,
$$
\gamma_{abc}=-\gamma_{bca}=-\gamma_{abc}\,.
$$
Then $\gamma_{abc}$ must be zero. $\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\Box$

- ***Consequence I***: When expressed in a coordinate basis, then the coefficients of the Christoffel, aka, Levi-Civita connection, $\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}\,,$ are known to be symmetric in $\mu,\nu$ since the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ is symmetric. Therefore, they can *never* be antisymmetric in $\rho$ and $\mu$ or $\rho$ and $\nu$ unless they are all zero.
- ***Consequence II***: In a non coordinate basis (moving frame, tetrad, vielbein), the coefficients of a torsion-free and metric compatible ***spin-connection***, ${{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^a}_b\,,$ [2] are known to be antisymmetric in $a$ and $b$ after the index $a$ got lowered with the Lorentz metric: $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\mu\,a\,b}=\eta_{ac}\,{{\boldsymbol{\omega}_\mu}^c}_b\,.$ Therefore, the components
  $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{\mu\,a\,b}$ can never be symmetric in $a$ and $\mu$
  or $b$ and $\mu\,,$ unless they are all zero.
- A typical example of a metric that has some antisymmetric Christoffel symbols is
  $$
  ds^2=\frac{dx^2+dy^2}{y^2}
  $$
  on the Poincare upper half plane model for hyperbolic geometry:
  $$
  \Gamma^x_{xy}=
  \Gamma^x_{yx}=
  \Gamma^y_{yy}=-y^{-1}\,,\quad
  \Gamma^y_{xx}=y^{-1}\,.
  $$
  Since $\Gamma^y_{yy}$ is not zero it is not antisymmetric in the upper and a  lower index. So the Lemma does not apply.

[1] T. Mueller, F. Grave, *A Catalogue of Spacetimes*, https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184.

[2] S. Carroll, *Spacetime and Geometry*.

Comment: Yes, precisely. Hence the problem I posted.